# Creating and Updating only a single value in Sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I want to create a new table in my `Database` (meaning I will have two tables). In that table I will only have one and only value and the use of that only value is I will get it and I will perform addition or subtraction and inserting/updating it again for the new value that has been subtracted or added values (basically it is an `integer` value or `boolean` for decimals). I'm still new at sqlite and a beginner at android development.

My Question is that how will I have/insert only one value in the table BY DEFAULT and how will I get and update it. Because when I add `INSERT` query in the activity itself or in the button/fab it will add new values each time I will open the fragment itself or press the button/fab. How will I have only one data in there BY DEFAULT and how to get it so I can add or subtract values in to it and update it for the new value?

I created two tables:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_CASHFLOW_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME2 + " (" +
                ItemEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                ItemEntry.COLUMN_INCOME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                ItemEntry.COLUMN_SAVINGS + " INTEGER NOT NULL " +
                ");";

        final String SQL_CREATE_ITEMLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                ItemEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                ItemEntry.COLUMN_LABEL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                ItemEntry.COLUMN_DETAIL + " TEXT, " +
                ItemEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                ItemEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT " +
                ");";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ITEMLIST_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CASHFLOW_TABLE);
    }
```

Codes I tried from bk7:

```
public void insertOrUpdateTheIncomeAndSavings(int income, int savings){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * from "+ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME2,null);
        if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            //update the values of first row here

            //update income
            Cursor cursor2 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME2+" SET "+ItemEntry.COLUMN_INCOME+
                    " = "+ income + " WHERE "+ItemEntry._ID +" = 1",null);

        }else{
            //insert the value here
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(ItemEntry.COLUMN_INCOME, 0);
            cv.put(ItemEntry.COLUMN_SAVINGS, 0);
        }

        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.close();
        }
        sqLiteDatabase.close();

    }
```

How can I do it in income java:

```
package com.example.admin.test2;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Income extends Fragment {

    public Income() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private EditText textInput;
    private FloatingActionButton fabPlus;
    private FloatingActionButton fabMinus;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_income, container, false);

        textInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        fabPlus = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabPlus);
        fabMinus = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabMinus);

        fabPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

and get values from this editText:

```
textInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

I want to display the input I inputted in the database in this textView but it does not work.. please check the code:

```
public void getIncome() {
        Cursor cur = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_INCOME + " as Income FROM " + ItemContract.ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME2
                , null);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

            int incomeTotal = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("Income"));// get final total
            income.setText("₱ " + incomeTotal);
        }
```

Comment: Hello @Joric Libiran, please share the code of what you have implemented so far.

Comment: @bk7 I haven't tried anything yet, I can't think of a way to implement this.. that is why I am asking a question now...

Comment: ok just create a Table with a sigle column and share the code, will try to help you.

Comment: wait, how can I create a column that already have a value? because I will just edit/update it?

Comment: create a table without value

Comment: done I added a table, but is this correct?

Comment: should we move to conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here were inserting first row if it does not exist and updating the first row is exists.

```
     public void insertOrUpdateTheIncomeAndSavings(int income, int savings){
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

          Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME2,null);
            if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            //update the values of first row here

            }else{
                //insert the value here
            }

            if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.close();
            }
           sqLiteDatabase.close();

        }
```

Edit: Add this in Onclick

```
 DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
  int income = Integer.valueOf(incomeEditText.getText().toString());
  int savings = Integer.valueOf(savingsEditText.getText().toString());
  dbhelper.insertOrUpdateTheIncomeAndSavings(income,savings);
```

Comment: i will put it in the dbhelper java? or in the java of the income and savings.. they have separated fragments btw

Comment: yes put in dbhelper and take care of inserting and updating value where i have comments

Comment: hello, please look at the codes if correct.. it has insert, will it keep the database to storee only one row/value???

Comment: are the codes I added correct? How can I implement it in the income java.. when I get data from editText

Comment: I added something in the question for the next problem I don't know what to do

Comment: it is edit for both income and savings, but I will have to separate them in two codes because it they are in different fragments

Comment: okay write two similar functions in dbhelper and just pass income or savings as a parameter

Comment: hello  the cursor2 that I created in the movetoNext() will I put another movetoNext/First or something? is that needed for the query to execute?

Comment: I wanted to display the value I inputted in the database and the value is not showing.. what can I do? please check my code, I added it.. btw it is in another fragment again that is why I used that codes.

Comment: use https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database  to check if data is properly inserting and updating.

Comment: while inserting you forgot to add **sqLiteDatabase.insert(ItemEntry.TABLE_NAME2,null, cv);** in **insertOrUpdateTheIncomeAndSavings** method while inserting the data.

Comment: wait I'll add it

Comment: hello again.. I am currently experiencing a problem.. the problem is when I input value the first time it goes well, but when I input value again the app crashes.. the only way for this for not to happen is changing fragments and going back to the income fragment and I can input again one value..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void updateEmployeeName(String empNo,String new_empname) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String empName = "";
    try {
        cursor = SQLiteDatabaseInstance_.rawQuery("SELECT EmployeeName 
        FROM Employee WHERE EmpNo=?", new String[] {empNo + ""});
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            empName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("EmployeeName"));
            update(empname);
        }else{
            update(new_empname);
        } 
      }finally {
        cursor.close();
     }
 }    

**Update single value use this query:-**
    public void update(){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ColumnName, newValue);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, Column + "= ?", new String[] {rowId});
}

    **delete single value use this query:-**

    public void delete_singlevalue(String newValue) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();          
            db.execSQL("delete from TABLE_NAME where 
            ColumnName="+"'"+newValue+"'");
            db.close();   
      }
```